How to securely store and reuse an Auth0 access token until it expires?
I have a function that generates an access token from the Auth0 management API, which I then use for authorization in my external API requests. Here's the function:
const generateBearerToken = async () => {
    try {
      const options = {
        method: 'POST',
        url: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_URL,
        headers: { 'content-type': 'application/json' },
        data: {
          client_id: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_CLIENT_ID,
          client_secret: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_CLIENT_SECRET,
          audience: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_AUDIENCE,
          grant_type: "client_credentials"
        }
      };
  
      const response = await axios(options);
      const { access_token } = response.data;
      console.log("Bearer token:", access_token);
      return access_token;
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error generating bearer token:', error?.response?.data);
      return null;
    }
  };

As Auth0 only allows to generate 1000 tokens per month, I want to store this token for each user until it expires, and then reuse it for subsequent external API requests (My token expiration period is 1 week).
Auth0 token generation limitaion
I have a few questions:

What should be the ideal safe way to save authorization token after generating it from Auth0 so that it can be reused until token expiry?
Is it safe to store the token in local storage?
What will be the logic if the token expires and regenerate the token again and storing it again?

This function fetches user details using an access token generated by generateBearerToken() function. Currently, it generates a new token every time it fetches the user. How to optimise this thing that it doesn't have to generate token every time to fetch the user?
const fetchUser = async () => {
    setIsFetching(true);
    const token = await generateBearerToken();
    
    if (token) {
      console.log(process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL);
      console.log("Access token from fetchUser:", token);
      
      const apiUrl = `${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL}fetchPatient`;
      const options = {
        method: "GET",
        url: apiUrl,
        headers: { "authorization":  `Bearer ${token}` },
      };
      console.log(options);
  
      axios(options)
        .then(response => {
          try {
            setIsFetching(false);
            setAccessToken(token);
          } catch (error) {
            console.error('Error parsing JSON:', error);
          }
        })
        .catch(error => console.error('Error fetching data:', error));
    } else {
      console.log("Access token is null, request not sent.");
      setIsFetching(false);
    }
};


Read this doc. It should answer most of your questions. If you have more questions after, search on stackoverflow (this has been asked many times before) and if you can't find the answer then, ask a new question: https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-browser-based-apps
